# Changing the Folder security permissions using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write some code to put a text file into a secure folder.  The folder has attributes already set to read-only so that the files within are secure and cannot be altered but still read.

The `FileSystemObject` will allow me to use the attribute property which I can set to 1 (read-only) but this is easily overridden.

My next port of call was to `GetAclInformation` etc.

I downloaded some code and I got through a large portion of it but, at `GetAclInformation` it crashes Excel.

I then continued to look and so used the `ADsSecurity` dll.  This returns an error stating

> the ActiveX cannot create the object.

I have downloaded a copy of the dll and put it into the windows\syswow64 directory and then registered it with RegSvr32 which returned a success.

I can add the references required and see the object in the object viewer.  But trying both late and early binding has no affect and it still errors saying the ActiveX cannot create the object.

Does anyone have any other ideas or a suggestion on what to try?

```
Sub TestApproval()

    Dim oSec As New ADsSecurity
    Dim oSd As Object, oDac1 As Object, oAce As Object

    Set oSec = New ADsSecurity
    Set oSd = oSec.GetSecurityDescriptor(CStr("FILE://C:\Test"))
    Set oDac1 = oSd.DiscretionaryAcl

    For Each oAce In oDac1
        Debug.Print oAce.trustee & "|" & oAce.AceType & "|" & oAce.AccessMask & "|" & oAce.AceFlags & "|" & oAce.Flags & "|" & oAce.ObjectType & "|" & oAce.InheritedObjectType
    Next oAce

    Set oSec = Nothing
    Set oSd = Nothing
    Set oDac1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post the full code - the small snippet you have supplied is not enough to diagnose the issue you are facing.

Comment: Thanks Robin for taking the time to respond.

The code for the first version is:

I will stick it in an alternative comment as there is only a limited number of characters...sadly the other code wont fit in

Comment: Sub TestApproval()
      Dim oSec As New ADsSecurity
      Dim oSd As Object,oDac1 As Object, oAce As Object
  
      Set oSec = New ADsSecurity
      Set oSd = oSec.GetSecurityDescriptor(CStr("FILE://C:\Test"))
      Set oDac1 = oSd.DiscretionaryAcl
  
      For Each oAce In oDac1
        Debug.Print oAce.trustee & "|" & oAce.AceType & "|" & oAce.AccessMask & "|" & oAce.AceFlags & "|" & oAce.Flags & "|" & oAce.ObjectType & "|" & oAce.InheritedObjectType
      Next oAce
  
      Set oSec = Nothing
      Set oSd = Nothing
      Set oDac1 = Nothing
    End Sub